# Problems clearing reports in Kaspersky 2016

Tags: internet-security, kaspersky

In the 2015 version of Kaspersky Internet security I would click the Clear button on the reports page and a dialogue would come up showing the various reports and giving me the options of which ones to clear. After selecting the reports I would click the second Clear button and they would be gone. In the 2016 version this no longer happens. When I click the Clear button there is no dialogue as before and the total number of Mbs and Kbs changes usually to a lower figure but if I click it again the figure changes again sometimes to another lower figure but worryingly sometimes to a higher figure. So what is going on here and how do I know whether anything has been cleared or not? I would like some clarification on this, is it a bug in the new version?